# How to add grades to both an individual student and course?

Tags: java

So I have a small studentregister program where I can add/edit/delete students and courses, and save them to files as arraylists (Students.dat and Courses.dat). I can freely add/edit/delete any at any time.

Now I want to be able to add Grades and accomplishment dates to the aforementioned students and courses.

To explain further, im using JFrame and comboboxes for this.

[image: Screenshot for clarity]

(combobox1) Select Student: (Student Objects from the Students.dat arraylist)

(combobox2) Select Course: (Course Objects from the Courses.dat arraylist)

Add Grade (string, converted to int): *textbox*
Add Date (string): *textbox*

I want to be able to print out the information like this (in for example a textarea), but also be able to edit or delete any line later on inside the file.

[image: Example of where it will be printed out line by line]

**Student** Object: Maria Wood (which was selected in combobar)

Maths 5, 14.03.2019
Biology 4, 14.03.2019
Chemistry 2, 14.03.2019

but I ALSO have to be able to display all the students in a course:

**Course** object: Maths (which was selected in combobar of same container):

Maria Wood 5, 14.03.2019
Paul Green 3, 14.03.2019
Cassidy Tree 2, 14.03.2019

So the Student takes the selected combobox's Course Object, grade (int) and date (string).
The Course at the same time takes the selected combobox's Student Object, grade (int) and date (string).

I cannot store these in a hashmap since it would need a key/value pair, not one key and two values.

I was thinking of having some sort of an ArrayList of ArrayLists or such inside the Student and Course classes..or maybe subclasses for both classes?
I need the Object (Student/Course), int(grade) and String(date) as parameters from this container.

But I have no ideas how to approach this situation.

I need to be able to add more courses to the same student, or more students to the same course. I also need to be able to edit or delete them afterwards.

Note that I will not be using databases for this.
I hope my explanation is clear enough..

Comment: "I cannot store these in a hashmap since it would need a key/value pair, not one key and two values."  --  Sure you can.  Just store the key and a `List` of values, or a key and a custom object as the value, or whatever works for you.

Comment: I think, some new class(es) should be involved. Maybe an `Exam` with a date and a `Map<Student, Grade>` where `Grade` is an `enum`.

Comment: I was thinking I'd want to use Map<Object, List> (is this correct?). So the student would takes <Course, grade&date (as list)> and the course takes <Student, grade&date>. This way I could save it inside the specific instances of student and course, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use and object which has as attributes the id (or Primary key)of the course, the id of the students, the grade and the date. And then you can store theese objects in a hashmap with value the object and as key you can concatenate the four attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I first tried making a  which technically worked but was awkward to use as i had less control over what was printed out in the end.

So i made a new Grade class which took (int) grade and (String) date parameters. The Grade instance was made right before the hashmaps are "updated". Stored to Student a  hashmap and at the same time a  hashmap to the course.
 This gave me easier access to methods like toString() in the keys and values. So yeah got everything working now, thanks for the ideas!